# How to avoid getting null value when using between on a stored procedure for two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, between

I'm trying to get a procedure that calls all the values of a table (Table1), but has different values on ColumnX: when a ColumnX value is between two values (MinValue and MaxValue) from two columns of another table (table2), it should maintain the value, but it should give a null value when ColumnX value is out of that range. For instance, if MinValue <= ColumnX >= MaxValue, then the row maintains its ColumnX value. But if it's not between those two, it should return a null value. And do the same for each row of Table1.

What I've tried until now gives a null value always, so I guess there might be some element I should change.

Here's the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_ModifiedTable1]  
    @Category NVARCHAR(15),
    @Element NVARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    SELECT 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Sector ORDER BY Description, RV.Id) AS Rank,
        RV.Id, RV.Category,
        -- Element,
        Sector, Description,
        "ColumnX" = CASE 
                       WHEN ColumnX BETWEEN CAST((SELECT MinValue FROM Table2 WHERE Category = @Category) AS DECIMAL(25, 10)) 
                                        AND CAST((SELECT MaxValue FROM Table2 WHERE Category = @Category) AS DECIMAL(25, 10))
                          THEN ColumnX
                          ELSE NULL
                    END
    FROM 
        Table1
    WHERE 
        RV.Category = @Category
    ORDER BY  
        Sector, Description
END
```

I'm not sure on how I should modify it to avoid getting all the values as null if they are between the range. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of CAST((select MinValue FROM Table2 WHERE Category = @Category) and CAST((select MaxValue FROM Table2 WHERE Category = @Category)AS decimal(25,10))? What is the original value of ColumnX?

Comment: The original value of ColumnX is decimal(25,10). And the values of MinValue and MaxValue are decimal(18, 2).

Comment: Not they type. The values.

Comment: What if you use >= and <= instead of between?
WHEN ColumnX >= CAST((select MinValue FROM Table2 WHERE Category = @Category) AS decimal(25,10)) AND ColumnX <= CAST((select MaxValue FROM Table2 WHERE Category = @Category)AS decimal(25,10))

Comment: One example: MinValue = 0.00, MaxValue= 50.00 and ColumnX= 13.0000000000

Comment: It gives a syntax error when using >= and <= instead of between.

Comment: Did you forgot to add the second ColumnX before <= ? It should be like ColumnX >= ... AND ColumnX <= ...

Comment: I forgot the AND. I corrected it, but still get null values.

Comment: I tried with some table variables, your query should return proper ColumnX. Same with mine (using >= and <=). Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: try plugging in hard coded values instead of variables to see if desired result is produced

Comment: I see the problem. It seems someone deleted the data of the example I was using. thanks for your help. It works now with my new example.